# Boundary defining function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm confused about the proof of Prop 5.43 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

> Prop 5.43 Every smooth manifold with boundary admits a boundary defining function.

A boundary defining function is defined just a few lines earlier:

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold with boundary, a boundary defining function for $M$ is a smooth function $f: M \to [0, \infty)$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = \partial M$ and $df_p \neq 0$ for all $p \in \partial M$.

The proof basically lets ${(U_\alpha, \phi_\alpha)}$ be a collection of smooth charts whose domains cover $M$; defines smooth functions $f_\alpha : U_\alpha \to [0, \infty)$, and lets ${\psi_\alpha}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to this cover. He defines $f = \sum_\alpha \psi_\alpha f_\alpha$, and then has the following equation:
\begin{equation}
df_p(v) = \sum_\alpha (f_\alpha (p) d \phi_\alpha \rvert_p(v) + \phi_\alpha(p) d f_\alpha \rvert_p (v)),
\end{equation}

My question is why does:

> $f = \sum_\alpha \psi_\alpha f_\alpha \Longrightarrow df_p(v) = \sum_\alpha (f_\alpha (p) d \phi_\alpha \rvert_p(v) + \phi_\alpha(p) d f_\alpha \rvert_p (v))?$

I don't have a lot of diff geo background other than the first five chapters of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, so if explanations could be confined to using that knowledge, it would help me out a lot. Thanks!

---

This seems like something that should be easy to see, but here's what I am thinking and am stuck on:

Let $v \in T_{p} M$, so $v: C^\infty (M) \to \mathbb{R}$, and $g \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$. If we use the definition of a differential, we get:
\begin{equation}
d f_p(v)(g) = v(g \circ f) = v (g \circ \sum_\alpha \phi_\alpha f_\alpha) = v (\sum_\alpha g \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha v \circ g \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha,
\end{equation}
where in the third equality, we used the linearity of the derivation $v$.

From looking at the expression we want, it seems like we use the chain rule property of derivations, but that would apply if our expression were $v \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha$ rather than what we have, which is $v \circ g \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are properties of the exterior derivative (linearity and product rule), and you can find it later in the book (**Theorem 14.24**). Namely, in the case of functions (0-forms) $f,g:M\to\mathbb{R}:$
$$d(f+g)=df+dg$$
and
$$d(fg)=f\,dg+g\,df.$$

You can directly prove it, knowing that $df_p(v)=v_pf.$ Linearity is by definition of a tangent vector, which is a linear map $v:C^{\infty}(M)\to\mathbb R$:
$$d(f+g)_p(v)=v_p(f+g)=v_pf+v_pg=df_p(v)+dg_p(v).$$
Since a tangent vector also checks the product rule $v_p(fg)=f(p)v_pg+g(p)v_pf$, the second one follows from a similar computation:
$$d(fg)_p(v)=v_p(fg)=f(p)v_pg+g(p)v_pf=f(p)dg_p(v)+g(p)df_p(v).$$

Comment: Thanks, I see indeed that Thm 14.24 does give me what I want. I would still like to know if there is a way to see this just from the material preceeding Prop 5.43; namely just the definition of a derivation, tangent space, etc.

Comment: Yes you can : I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm looking at the definition of a differential and seeing $df_p(v)(g) = v(g \circ f)$, but it seems you have it defined $df_p(v) = v_p f$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes: the differential you are talking about is also named the push-forward, sending a tangent vector to another one (the one which eats $g$ and returns $v(g\circ f)$). The differential here eats a tangent vector $v_p$ and returns a scalar $v_pf$. There is a correspondance between the two: since a tangent vector in $\mathbb R$ is written $\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, you identify the scalar $\alpha$ with the tangent vector $\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. Some authors write $f_*$ when they talk about the push-forward, and $df$ for the differential (for $f:M\to\mathbb R$.)

Comment: ... the relation being $f_*(v_p)=df_p(v_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Thanks for your super quick and helpful response. I definitely feel like this is exactly the solution I'm looking for, and all the ingredients for resolving my confusion are here, but I'm not making the final step in my head that makes it all click. Is there some way to make it more explicit? Like is $g = \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$? I see that we can write tangent vectors in a basis of partial derivatives, but I'm hoping there is some way to directly see how $df_p(v)(g) = v(g \circ f) \rightarrow df_p(v) = v_{p} f$.

Comment: First beware that $g$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, not a tangent vector. And indeed for a special $g$, namely the identity $t\mapsto t$, you can check what you want: $f_*(v_p)(\mathrm{id})=v_p(\mathrm{id}\circ f)=v_p(f)$, so $f_*(v_p)=v_p(f)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ (since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mathrm{id})=\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}=1$). I don't know if this answers your question?

Comment: Hmmm I'm still a bit confused because it seems like if I take the definition $d f_p (v) = v_p f$ and/or the exterior derivative defined in Chapter 14, then I can get what I want. But if I take the definition that has been introduced at this point, namely $d f_p (v)(g) = v(g \circ f)$, for any smooth $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then I cannot get what I want. I see that it works for a special $g$, the identity; but the definition on page 55 of the second edition of ISM says that we need to hold for general smooth $g$. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something important conceptually.

Comment: I think I did not get what you want to show then (i.e. I misunderstand when you write $df_p(v)(g) = v(g \circ f) \rightarrow df_p(v) = v_{p} f$), can you re-explain me what do you want at this point (and sorry, I won't be able to answer until 5/6 hours)?

Comment: Definitely, and no worries! So I want to understand why $f = \sum_\alpha \psi_\alpha f_\alpha \Longrightarrow df_p(v) = \sum_\alpha (f_\alpha (p) d \phi_\alpha \rvert_p(v) + \phi_\alpha(p) d f_\alpha \rvert_p (v))$. It seems rather obvious, but the only definition provided in the book so far is that $d f_p (v)(g) = v(g \circ f)$. So if I want to understand what $d (\sum_\alpha \phi_\alpha f_\alpha)$ means, I will have to go through this definition. ...

Comment: But that leads to $d f_p(v)(g) = v(g \circ f) = v (g \circ \sum_\alpha \phi_\alpha f_\alpha) = v (\sum_\alpha g \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha v \circ g \circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha$, at which point I cannot make any progress, because $g$ is just a general smooth function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. It would be really nice to get rid of the function $g$, but it doesn't seem like I can, because if I get rid of $g$, then I can use the fact that $v$ is a derivation as finish off the problem as you did above in your solution.

Comment: I think I understand now, and this may be an inconsistency of the book. Indeed you only have the definition you are talking about , but see how the author writes $df_p(v)>0$: what does it mean for a tangent vector to be positive? He thinks about this quantity as $v_pf$. However we can still do the proof considering only $g=\mathrm{id}$, as we discussed above, since the aim of the proof is to show that $df_p\neq 0$: so we just have to find a tangent vector $v$ and a smooth function $g$ such that $df_p(v)g\neq 0$. An inward pointing vector and $\mathrm{id}$ do the job.

Comment: Also note that for general $g$, you don't have $g \circ \sum_\alpha \phi_\alpha f_\alpha=\sum_\alpha g\circ \phi_\alpha f_\alpha$: $g$ has to be linear for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let me go digest this for a bit; will mark as solution once I have a chance to digest it

Comment: This issue also comes up on page 134. I wouldn't say I completely understand it, because it does seem from the definition that you do need it to work for general $g$, but the book does discuss this later on (page 281 in chapter 11), just as you mentioned, so hopefully it will make more sense when I get there. For now, I'll just take the properties of the differential in Prop 11.20 for granted. Thanks so much for your super helpful responses!!

Comment: You are welcome! Also, I know that John M. Lee is on this forum (@JackLee), perhaps it would be useful to talk to him about that, since I don't see any mention about it in his errata (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/errata.pdf). Anyway, have a good reading, this book is pure joy!

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there a way to tag @JackLee?

Comment: I thought that just tagging him like we did would suffice, but I don't really know, and I don't know either how to send a message to an user. Perhaps the simpliest way is to send him a mail at johnmlee@uw.edu, since he is telling us to do so on his webpage?

Comment: That sounds great, many thanks @Balloon!

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed this question. This was a big oversight on my part -- when I wrote that equation for $df_p$, I was thinking of $df_p$ as a covector, conveniently blanking out the fact that covectors aren't introduced until Chapter 11.

Instead, I should have phrased this in terms of the action of vectors on functions. Here's what I should have written, starting two lines above the displayed formula for $df_p$ on page 119:

> For each $\alpha$ such that $p\in U_\alpha$, we have $f_\alpha(p)=0$ and $v(f_\alpha) = v^n>0$ by Proposition 5.41. Thus
> $$
> v(f) = \sum_\alpha \big( f_\alpha(p) v(\psi_\alpha) + \psi_\alpha(p) v(f_\alpha)\big).
> $$
> For each $\alpha$, the first term in parentheses is zero and the second is nonnegative, and there is at least one $\alpha$ for which the second term is positive. Thus $v(f)>0$, which implies that $df_p(v) = (vf) d/dt\big|_{f(p)}\ne 0$, where $t$ is the standard coordinate on $\mathbb R$.

**EDIT:** I just added this as a correction in my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/ISM/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's very helpful to resolve my concerns. Also great book!

Answer (score 3):

This answer may no longer be useful to you, but I had similar concerns while working through this part of the proof. Here's an answer that only relies on techniques present in the book up to this point.

Here if $F: M \to N$ is a smooth map and $p \in M$, the notation $dF_p$ will mean the differential as defined in Lee's book, so it is a linear map $dF_p: T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$.

Let $F, G \in C^{\infty}(M)$, so $F$ and $G$ are smooth functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$.

First of all, it doesn't seem that the statement $d(FG)_p = F(p) dF_p + G(p)dG_p$ makes much sense in general, because $dF_p$ is a map $T_pM \to T_{F(p)}\mathbb{R}$ while $dG_p$ is a map $T_pM \to T_{G(p)}\mathbb{R}$ and $d(FG)_p$ is a map $T_pM \to T_{(FG)(p)}\mathbb{R}$. In general, $F(p)$, $G(p)$ and $F(p)G(p)$ may all be distinct so the codomains are not even the same.

However, if we assume that $F(p) = 0$ we can prove the following version of the "product rule" for differentials:

> **Theorem 1**: Let $F, G \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $p \in M$. Suppose $F(p) = 0$. Then $d(FG)_p = G(p)dF_p$.

---

**Proof of Theorem 1**

Let $v \in T_pM$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Then $d(FG)_p(v)f = v(f \circ (FG))$. By Lemma 2 below, $v(f \circ (FG)) = f'((FG)(p)) v(FG)$. Then by the product rule for derivations, we obtain $$d(FG)_p(v)f = f'(0)G(p)vF = G(p)f'(F(p))vF = G(p) v(f \circ F) = G(p) dF_p(v)f$$ where we used Lemma 2 again. This holds for any $v$ and $f$ so $d(FG)_p = G(p) dF_p$.

---

In the case we are interested in, we want to find $d(\psi_\alpha f_\alpha)_p$.

For each $\alpha$ such that $p \in U_\alpha$ (where $U_\alpha$ is the open cover that the partition of unity is subordinate to), we have $f_\alpha(p) = 0$ so Theorem 1 shows that $d(\psi_\alpha f_\alpha)_p = \psi_\alpha(p) d(f_\alpha)_p$.

For the other $\alpha$, we have $\psi_\alpha(p) = 0$ (because $U_\alpha$ must then be an interior chart) and so Theorem 1 shows that $d(\psi_\alpha f_\alpha)_p = f_\alpha(p) d(\psi_\alpha)_p$.
But for any $v \in T_pM$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(R)$ we have
$$d(\psi_\alpha)_p(v)f = v(f \circ \psi_\alpha) = v(0) = 0$$ since $\psi_\alpha = 0$ on a neighborhood of $p$ when $p$ is not in $U_\alpha$ (assume that $\overline{U_\alpha} \cap ∂M$ is empty, which can be done by shrinking the $U_\alpha$ if necessary). Hence $d(\psi_\alpha f_\alpha)_p = 0$.

So we have $$df_p = \sum\limits_{\alpha\colon p \in U_\alpha} \psi_\alpha(p) d(f_\alpha)_p$$

Note also that $f(p) = 0$ since $f_\alpha(p) = 0$ for each $\alpha$ such that $p \in U_\alpha$ and the codomains of each differential in the sum are the same, $T_0\mathbb{R}$).

Then $$df_p(v) = \sum\limits_{\alpha\colon p \in U_\alpha} \psi_\alpha(p) d(f_\alpha)_p(v)$$

This result is good enough to complete the proof of Lee's Proposition.

---

Lemma 2 provides an analogue of the chain rule for derivations:

> **Lemma 2**: Suppose $F \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. Then $dF_p(v)f = v(f \circ F) = f'(F(p)) vF$.

**Proof of Lemma 2**:

Let $(U, \varphi)$ be a smooth chart for $M$ containing $p$. With respect to this chart, we can write $v$ as a linear combination in terms of the standard basis for $T_pM$:

$$v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_p$$

Then we compute

$$v(f \circ F) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i\frac{\partial(f \circ F)}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_p = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i\frac{\partial(f \circ F \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_{\varphi(p)} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i f'(F(p))\frac{\partial(F \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_{\varphi(p)}$$ by the ordinary chain rule
$$ = f'(F(p))\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial(F \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_{\varphi(p)} = f'(F(p))\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}\bigg\vert_p = f'(F(p)) vF$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I just noticed this question (thanks to your answer, which popped this up to the top of the list). See my answer below.